# Can scatter plot points be expanded?

Tags: highcharts, explode, scatter

I'm trying to create an 'average' point in a scatter chart that when clicked, will expand to show the 'component' points, similar to how Hans Roslings 'Gapminder' application does to provide more detail from aggregate/container points.

Is this something that Highcharts can do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'Gapminder', are you looking for a bubble chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble?

Comment: @Mark Almost.  I'd like the ability to click on a bubble, and that bubble expand to show the points that make up that 'average' bubble.  Basically, expand a nested data array stored in the bubble.

Comment: Something similar is done [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) but for columns. Adopt that example to your needs.

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks, but I'm not looking for a full drilldown, just to explode an aggregate point into its components.  Trying to find an image somewhere to describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think I know what do you want, just after click on a scatter point, split into several smaller dots. Something like this isn't supported in other way than drilldown. But in general would work the same way - after click, remove clicked point and add new series which is under that point.